# Addend HTML With HTML Behaviors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am appending, using jQuery, a HTML button with a autofocus feature. However, 
the autofocus feature is not working. I have tired focusing this using jQuery and css. It seems their is a disconnect with the loaded html and appended html but I am not finding good resources on the topic.

```
var modal = " \
<div id='disable-modal' class='modalDialog'> \
    <div id='modal-container'> \
      <div id='modal-banner'> \
        <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a> \
      </div> \
      <h1>Are you sure you want to restore<br>H's homepage?</h1> \
      <button is='x-disable-extension-button' class='yes-button'>Yes</button> \
      <button href='#close' class='no-button' autofocus >No</button> \

    </div> \
 </div>";
$('body').append(modal);
```

Comment: Wheres the code to autofocus?

Comment: @tymeJV (The attribute)

Comment: Works for me with a little change to how you build that string. http://jsfiddle.net/pLc352fx/

Comment: Beat me to it @tymeJV

Comment: In using jQuery to focus the button, did you bind to it through a static parent element, or were you trying to bind directly to it?

Comment: @brso05 in safari at least that fiddle doesn't work for me: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Comment: If the extra line break between the button and the div in the code above it removed it works fine.

Comment: @epascarello correct!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kfbkj5ue/3/

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra line break in the code above that is causing it to not execute. The line between the last button and closing div needs to be removed. If you remove it, it runs fine.

```js
var modal = " \
<div id='disable-modal' class='modalDialog'> \
    <div id='modal-container'> \
      <div id='modal-banner'> \
        <a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a> \
      </div> \
      <h1>Are you sure you want to restore<br>H's homepage?</h1> \
      <button is='x-disable-extension-button' class='yes-button'>Yes</button> \
      <button href='#close' class='no-button' autofocus >No</button> \
    </div> \
 </div>";
$('body').append(modal);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If that is just a typo, than maybe you can manually do it.

```
$(modal).appendTo("body").find("[autofocus]").focus();
```

Comment: Thank you I must've just put the extra space in as a typo when copy the text over. but I believe the problem is that this text I am appending is a modal and when a user goes to click on the a tag to open the modal the no button must loose it's focus.

Answer (score 0):

@tymeJV is the correct answer...

```
var modal = "<div id='disable-modal' class='modalDialog'> "
    + "<div id='modal-container'> "
     + "<div id='modal-banner'> "
        + "<a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>"
      + "</div> "
      + "<h1>Are you sure you want to restore<br>H's homepage?</h1> "
      + "<button is='x-disable-extension-button' class='yes-button'>Yes</button> "
      + "<button href='#close' class='no-button' autofocus >No</button> "
    + "</div>"
 + "</div>";
$('body').append(modal);
$('#close').focus();
```

Comment: It look better of course through convention but it does not solve the autofocus problem

Answer (score 0):

All browsers don't support "autofocus" e.g IE10 doesn't but Chrome or FireFox supports "autofocus". Your code works perfectly in Chrome or FireFox if the modal string is formatted properly. Please test in other browser!

Comment: I'm running this in chrome. I have a a tag to active the modal. try the text appending modal to see if the and opening the modal through a tag because when the modal opens autofocus doesn't  works.